# keep clicked node as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have working bootstrap treeview plugin. currently it works like, when user clicks on node once. it select the node. but if user click it again on same node. it deselect the node.

I am trying to change it like: if user clicks on node it select the node. until user clicks on any other node, but if user clicks on same node more than once. it should stay selected.  it shouldn't be deselect.

I hope I have cleared enough my question.

https://jsfiddle.net/evk9yfum/

```
   var initSelectableTree = function () {
            return $('#treeview-selectable').treeview({
                levels: 1,
                data: defaultData,
                enableLinks: true,
                onNodeSelected: function (event, node) {
                    //$('.contanter').css('background','green');
                },
                onNodeUnselected: function (event, node) {
                    //$('.contanter').css('background','red');
                }
            });
        };
        var $selectableTree = initSelectableTree();

    });
```

Comment: I can't tell if your indentation is messed up or not. `$selectableTree` won't ever be instantiated because you are returning before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code snippet will do the trick for you. Hope this will help you.

```
var initSelectableTree = function () {
    return $('#treeview-selectable').treeview({
        levels: 1,
        data: defaultData,
        enableLinks: true,
        onNodeSelected: function (event, node) {
            $(this).treeview('unselectNode', [node.nodeId, { silent: false }]);
        },
        onNodeUnselected: function (event, node) {
            $(this).treeview('selectNode', [node.nodeId, { silent: true }]);
        },
        onNodeCollapsed:function(event, node){
            $.each(node.nodes, function(){
                if(this.state.selected){
                   $('#treeview-selectable').treeview('selectNode', 
                                  [ node.nodeId, { silent: true } ]); 
                   return;
                }
            });     
        }
    });
};
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evk9yfum/9/

Comment: so is this possible now, if child element selected and user collapsed the parent then I want to show parent as selected. To show something is selected inside this collapsed element. Eg: if Fördertechnik 1665 > Förderbahnen > Bautelle is selected and user collapsed Fördertechnik (2nd li) and it should show selected.

Comment: You are welcome. See the updated answer for selecting parent node in `onNodeCollapsed` event if any child is selected.

Comment: Thank you Azim... please have look to new question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309821/oncollapse-set-parent-as-selected-node-if-child-grandchild-is-already-selected