# onCollapse set parent as selected node, if child/grandchild is already selected (bootstrap treeView)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, treeview

I have working bootstrap tree view. I want add one feature in this.

https://jsfiddle.net/evk9yfum/

https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview (plugin used)

Eg:  onNodeCollapsed: if collapsed node's child/grandChild already selected. then current collpased node should be shown as selected node.

Then on expand of this same node. it should show its/last selected or child/grandChild node.

```
onNodeCollapsed: function(event, node) {
    $.each(node.nodes, function() {
      if (this.state.selected) {
        $('#treeview-selectable').treeview('selectNode', [node.nodeId, {
          silent: true
        }]);
        return;
      }
    });
  }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this `var slectedNodeId, hasSelect=false, nodeIdList=[]` three global variable and then do like the code below. Hope this will help you.

```
onNodeExpanded:function(event, node){                    
      $.each(node.nodes, function(){ 
            if((this.nodeId==slectedNodeId || nodeIdList.indexOf(this.nodeId)>-1) 
                && hasSelect)
            {
                 $('#treeview-selectable').treeview('selectNode', 
                              [ this.nodeId, { silent: true } ]);
            }
      });  
}, 
onNodeCollapsed:function(event, node){
       nodeIdList.push(node.nodeId);
       $.each(node.nodes, function(){ 
             if(this.state.selected){
                 $('#treeview-selectable').treeview('selectNode', 
                                 [nodeIdList[0], { silent: true } ]);
                 hasSelect=true;
             }
       });     
},
onNodeSelected: function (event, node) {
       slectedNodeId=node.nodeId;
       nodeIdList=[];
       hasSelect=false;

       $(this).treeview('unselectNode', [ node.nodeId, { silent: false } ]);
},
onNodeUnselected: function (event, node) {
       $(this).treeview('selectNode', [ node.nodeId, { silent: true } ]);             
}
```

Updated Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/evk9yfum/24/): https://jsfiddle.net/evk9yfum/24/